# Find inactive GameObject by name, tag or layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, I need to deactivate a game object and then after 10 seconds, activate it, so I thought coroutines are suitable:

```
IEnumerator BarDeactivate(float sec)
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);

        var obj = GameObject.Find("OBJ");
        obj.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator BarReactivate(float sec)
{
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);

        var obj = transform.Find("OBJ");
        obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

Obviously, I can no longer use `GameObject.Find` so I use `transform.Find` to find the **inactive** game object, but of course `.SetActive` now does not work, since obj is not actually a game object...

How do I cast the found transform, so that it can be set active again?

I tried `obj.gameObject.SetActive(true)` but it must be wrong, because the object would not come back to life...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is that Unity cannot find inactive GameObjects. `GameObject.Find` will only find active GameObject. You should either find and store the GameObject in a global variable or make the variable public then assign it from the Editor.

My solution uses a global variable then stores the GameObject in the beginner so that you don't have to look for it again.

```
GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    obj = GameObject.Find("OBJ");
}
IEnumerator BarDeactivate(float sec)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
    obj.SetActive(false);
}

IEnumerator BarReactivate(float sec)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
    obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

---

Below is a wrapper I made that finds GameObjects by name, tag or layer even if they are inactive.

You shouldn't be using these every frame because they are slow. They are good if used in the `Start` or `Awake` function.

**Find one GameObject:**

**USAGE:**

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject objByName = FindInActiveObjectByName("Cube");
    GameObject objByTag = FindInActiveObjectByTag("CubeTag");
    GameObject objByLayer = FindInActiveObjectByLayer(LayerMask.NameToLayer("CubeLayer"));
}
```

Find in-active GameObject by Name:

```
GameObject FindInActiveObjectByName(string name)
{
    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].name == name)
            {
                return objs[i].gameObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Find in-active GameObject by Tag:

```
GameObject FindInActiveObjectByTag(string tag)
{

    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].CompareTag(tag))
            {
                return objs[i].gameObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Find in-active GameObject by Layer:

```
GameObject FindInActiveObjectByLayer(int layer)
{

    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].gameObject.layer == layer)
            {
                return objs[i].gameObject;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

---

**Find all GameObjects** (Notice the **"s"** in the Object from all the function names below):

**USAGE:**

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject[] objByNames = FindInActiveObjectsByName("Cube");
    GameObject[] objByTags = FindInActiveObjectsByTag("CubeTag");
    GameObject[] objByLayers = FindInActiveObjectsByLayer(LayerMask.NameToLayer("CubeLayer"));
}
```

Find in-active GameObject[s] by Name:

```
GameObject[] FindInActiveObjectsByName(string name)
{
    List<GameObject> validTransforms = new List<GameObject>();
    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].gameObject.name == name)
            {
                validTransforms.Add(objs[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
    return validTransforms.ToArray();
}
```

Find in-active GameObject[s] by Tag:

```
GameObject[] FindInActiveObjectsByTag(string tag)
{
    List<GameObject> validTransforms = new List<GameObject>();
    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].gameObject.CompareTag(tag))
            {
                validTransforms.Add(objs[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
    return validTransforms.ToArray();
}
```

Find in-active GameObject[s] by Layer:

```
GameObject[] FindInActiveObjectsByLayer(int layer)
{
    List<GameObject> validTransforms = new List<GameObject>();
    Transform[] objs = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll<Transform>() as Transform[];
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        if (objs[i].hideFlags == HideFlags.None)
        {
            if (objs[i].gameObject.layer == layer)
            {
                validTransforms.Add(objs[i].gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
    return validTransforms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case [Invoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) is a better option than a coroutine. Also, as far as I know you cannot .Find an inactive object, so you should assign the found object to a field.

```
var obj;

void BarDeactivate(){
    obj = GameObject.Find("OBJ");
    obj.SetActive(false);
}

void BarReactivate(){
    obj.SetActive(true);
}
```

Call them via Invoke like this:

```
Invoke("BarDeactivate", sec);
Invoke("BarReactivate", sec);
```

Comment: It works! Many thanks. Though I had to mark the other answer as accepted, because in this case, it built on my coroutine solution and resolved it, but your answer is so elegant and helpful. I tried it in a slightly-different situation and it works like a charm. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue with ARCore, Vuforia, etc. because GameObjects are not alive until they can be tracked. One way is wait for the target to be recognized and then look for the GameObjects, but if they are manually inactive the only other (uncomplicated?) way would be to manually list them and link them as a public array with the script. If your script is linked then even an inactive GameObject will be accessible.

Answer (score 0):

you can find deactivate `gameobject` through code and assign in inspector on run time:

**1-** attach script on gameobject which you have to get. `e.g i have attach " PoliceCarController ";`

**2 -** write a code

```
void Start()
{ 
 GameObject PoliceCar = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PoliceCarController>(true).gameObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a parent GO that is always active, and kids that might or might not be active, you can use something like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find a GO. It might be inactive.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parentName">Name of parent GO. Must be active.</param>
    /// <param name="gameObjectName">Name of GO to find.</param>
    /// <returns>GO, or null.</returns>
    public static GameObject FindMaybeDisabledGameObjectByName(string parentName, string gameObjectName)
    {
        GameObject go = GameObject.Find(parentName);
        if (go == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        Transform childTransform
            = go.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true).FirstOrDefault(
                t => t.name == gameObjectName
            );
        if (childTransform == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return childTransform.gameObject;
    }
```