# Could Unity script listen to events and active self at certain circumstance?

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I want to make a common alert window to show information about some info maybe warning, tutorial etc,

I think it will be good if there is a way that the alert widget(mostly just a box  border, a close button, the info text and some hint sign stuff) could pop up when there is event received, so in the game I could just shoot the msg through a static method, and the widget could just pop up.

I have no problem to do the event part, but I couldn't find a way to active the gameobject of the widget since it will be deactivated as the game started, and seems couldn't assign itself the event pool.

Is there a way to do that? Or how you deal with the problem?

[image]

And here is the event assignment so far I have complete:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class WarningTextUGUIController : MonoBehaviour {

    private Text text;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        text = GetComponent<Text>();
        text.text = ApplicationModel.CurrentErrMsg;
        ApplicationModel.OnErrMsg += ChangeErrMsg;
    }

    private void ChangeErrMsg(string msg, bool isNgui)
    {
        if (!isNgui)
        {
            text.text = msg;
            if (!gameObject.transform.parent.parent.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                gameObject.transform.parent.parent.localScale = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
                gameObject.transform.parent.parent.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                LeanTween.scale(gameObject.transform.parent.parent.gameObject, new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f), 0.2f).setEase(LeanTweenType.easeInBounce);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        ApplicationModel.OnErrMsg -= ChangeErrMsg;
    }

}
```

I must note that things will work if I made the widget active at the beginning of the game, but I have to disable it because it's shouldn't be seen under most circumstances.

Comment: Create an EventManager you can subscribe to. When something happens that EventManager is responsible for alerting scripts that subscribed to it. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034245/unity-eventmanager-with-delegate-instead-of-unityevent/42034899#42034899)

Comment: thanks，I'll try that

Comment: @Programmer : The problem is that `WarningTextUGUIController` won't be able to subscribe to the EventManager since it is disabled when the app starts.

Comment: Hey, @Hellium do you have other solution for this?

Comment: The only way I can think about is to leave the gameobject enabled in the SceneView and disable it in the Awake/Start method after you have subscribed to the event.

Comment: Put that pop up message in a empty game object and attach event listener to it, so it can enable or disable pop up as needed.

Comment: Or instead of enabling and disabling objects just toggle renderers.

Comment: @Hellium That's not a problem at-all. This is why there is an `Awake` function. The `Awake` function is called **even** when the script is disabled. OP can just register the event in the `Awake` function.

Comment: @Programmer I found the solution you give in other question couldn't meet my needs since I couldn't easily pass parameters to the listener, I found a bypass way to do that: first, make the scale to vector3.zero at `Start()` and then change the scale to make it pop up.

Comment: `Awake` is not called if the **gameobject** is disabled. In edit mode, I understand that the "error pop-up" is on the way and may be disabled and it's tedious to disable/enable the gameobject when you edit your game.

Comment: @Programmer, I have tried to subscribe to the event in `Awak()` but It seems don't work, don't know whether have done something wrong :-( frankly I don't know if the script will be ever executed if the gameobject will not be active during the game.

Comment: @Hellium In your first comment you said if `WarningTextUGUIController` is disable. `WarningTextUGUIController` is a script. I am talking about the script. If the script is disabled, the `Awake` will be called. I am replying to your first comment. Also you can't disable/enable a GameObject, you can deactivate and activate it. You enable and disable scripts. Just saying that so that you won't confuse people in the future.

Comment: @armnotstrong I've answered that question before and I am looking for it to link it here but can't find it. You need a way to subscribe  to the event. You have **2** options: **1**.Make the Object enabled by default then disable it in the `Awake` function after subscribing to the event. **2**.Modify the `EventManager` script and make manually make it subscribe to the function in the  `WarningTextUGUIController` script by searching for it with `GameObject.Find` the `GetComponent.  It's really easy.

Comment: @Programmer thanks, enable and disable it in the `Awake()` is a good inspire, maybe I should throw it far away and make it back too, so it doesn't block the scene when editing stuff :D

Comment: I can see that being really annoying when it's blocking the screen. I have another idea. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456334/3785314) answer I left, you will see functions I wrote that can be used to find inactive GameObjects by tag, name, or layer. Deactivate the GameObject from the Editor. From the `EventManager` script, use `FindInActiveObjectByName` to find the disabled GameObject then use `GetComponent` to get `WarningTextUGUIController` script from it. Have a public function in the `WarningTextUGUIController` script that you will call to subscribe to the event.