# Unity auto hide panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am building an AR app using Unity.

It has login/register scenes that let the user login or register with the app.

For error handling and displaying error messages to the user (e.g. invalid email), I simply create a Panel with some text on it to display the error messages. There is also a Button on this Panel to close the message and hide the error panel again.

This panel is overlaid over the main UI Panel that has the input fields on it.

Obviously, the error panel should be hidden when the scene is loaded and only be displayed if there is an error message.

But I am unable to set the state of this panel on *Awake()*.
I keep getting the error ***NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.***

I have set the script to the error panel and added the Panel object to the script in the Inspector. image attached for reference.

Below is my abbreviated code (*using* omitted for brevity).
I have tried setting it in *Start()* and *Awake()* but both throw the same error.
If I set *errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(**true**);* in *Awake()* - no error is thrown. It is only thrown when it is set to *false*

```
public class RegisterScene : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject errorPanel; // Error panel

    void Awake()
    {
        errorPanel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("errorPanel"); // Error panel Tag
        Debug.Log("Error Panel: " + errorPanel); // Outputs "ErrorPanel" as named in Inspector
        errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Have to hide on scene Awake - throws NullReferenceError here
        //errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true); // This works as a test case
    }

    // Register button clicked
    public void Register ()
    {
        // If error 
        showErrorPanel("You must complete all sections");
    }

    // Show error panel
    public void showErrorPanel(string errorMessage)
    {
        Debug.Log("Showing error panel");
        errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true); // Working - shows error panel

        // Confirmation button on error panel clicked
        hideErrorPanel();
    }

    // Hide error panel
    public void hideErrorPanel()
    {
        Debug.Log("Hiding error panel");
        errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false); // Working - hides error panel
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is no order of when Awake() is called on each object. (Unless you specify a script order and that's just cheating).  So your RegisterScene is Awake before your errorPanel.  The rule of thumb is "get references in Awake" and "perform interactions in Start".  If you have to do it in Awake for some reason, you have to test for NULL on errorPanel first.  Then let errorPanel set its default state as inactive.

Comment: The `RegisterScene` script in your question is not the-same with the one attached to your GameObject. You removed so many code and I think the problem might be coming from there. Make sure save the script, run it again from the Editor then double-click on the error. It will take you to where the error is. Make sure this  is where you said the error is coming from.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow @jiveturkey I have dragged my C# RegisterScene script into my ErrorPanel in the Hierarchy. Then I dragged that panel to the GameObject in the Inspector. Does this not mean that my code will be called on Awake even though all my elements share the same RegisterScene script?

Comment: @Programmer yip I have done that and all the code I omitted was irrelevant to the question. I double clicked the error previously and it takes me to the line I noted in the code above where the error is being thrown.

Comment: My apologies, I could not see the pic.  Thanks for the explanation.  One question, are there any more ErrorPanel's? You should probably be calling GetComponentInChildren<>

Comment: @jiveturkey no there aren't any other ErrorPanels set. As a test I created a test panel and that gave the same error.

Comment: See @Programmer Answer below

Answer (score 1):

> If I set `errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(true);` in `Awake()` - no
>   error is thrown. It is only thrown when it is set to false.

Here is likely what's happening:

Your `RegisterScene` script is attached to **another** GameObject. When `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("errorPanel")` is called, your panel is returned. When you set it to `false` with `errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive(false)`, it deactivates it.

The `Awake` function will then be called on the **other** GameObject it is attached to which will also call `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("errorPanel")` but will return `null` this time. It will return `null` because the `GameObject.FindXXX` functions **cannot** find de-activated Objects. Because it is `null`, calling `errorPanel.gameObject.SetActive` will throw that exception.

You have two options:

**1**.Find and remove the script from other GameObject:

[image]

**2**.Use my [`FindInActiveObjectByTag`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44456334/3785314) function to find de-activated GameObjects if you need to find inactive GameObjects.